# IE 9 does not follow selectedIndex upon refresh

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu

I set the value of a drop down using JavaScript to "Peter" upon loading of the page.

I noticed in IE 9 .0.28 once you load the page, "Peter" is selected. If you set the drop down to "John" and refresh the page, "John" stays selected.

In fact, if you insert an alert statement you will see upon refresh with alert window popped up that "Peter" is selected correctly in the dropdown. But after you click OK, "John" is selected again.

Upgrading IE is not an option. Other browsers are fine.

Here is the code to reproduce:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head><title>getElementById method (Internet Explorer)</title></head>

<body>
<form>
<input type='hidden' id='theName' value='Peter' />
<select id="employees" size="1">
<option value="">John</option>
<option value="">Peter</option>
</select>
</form>         

<script type="text/javascript">

var theName = document.getElementById('theName').value;
var theDropdown = document.getElementById('employees');

for (var i = 0; i < theDropdown.options.length; i++) {
    if (theDropdown.options[i].innerHTML === theName) {
            theDropdown.selectedIndex = i;
            alert("Hooooold");
            break;
        }
    }

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

Any way to solve this with code only?

Comment: Only java-script will not cause this issue. Which Framework your using?

Comment: Not sure what you mean with framework. I can reproduce this with just IE 9. I am in a corporate setting where PCs are managed. So it might be the admins did something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your script logic inside onLoad event

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">

<head>
    <title>getElementById method (Internet Explorer)</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <input type='hidden' id='theName' value='Peter' />
        <select id="employees" size="1">
            <option value="">John</option>
            <option value="">Peter</option>
        </select>
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() {
            var theName = document.getElementById('theName').value;
            var theDropdown = document.getElementById('employees');
            for (var i = 0; i < theDropdown.options.length; i++) {
                if (theDropdown.options[i].innerHTML === theName) {
                    theDropdown.selectedIndex = i;
                    alert("Hooooold");
                    break;
                }
            }
        };
    </script>


</body>

</html>
```

This works :)

Comment: Thanks it does. Any idea why it does not work my way?

Comment: Refresh doesn't re-execute scripts . Here in your case to keep 'peter' in dropdown, you have to force it to re-execute the script on refresh.

Comment: The refresh does not re-execute scripts in IE 9? Because it does in Chrome.